# Excel Hyperlink- When clicked make target cell always upper left hand corner

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a very wide excel spreadsheet. It's formatted in such a way that there is specific data on each screen page.  I have the first column frozen so I can place hyperlink buttons vertically.  These buttons are hyperlinked to each of the formatted pages in the worksheet.

When I click one of the hyperlink buttons I would like the worksheet to scroll so the target cell in the UPPER LEFT corner of the screen.

I have googled and found this VBA code to place in the "thisworkbook" section of the VBA editor.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
     ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
     ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = ActiveCell.Column
 End Sub
```

This code does not seem to work for me.  If I'm at the far left of the screen and press the hyperlink button it scrolls to the target cell until it gets on the active screen.  So basically it always ends up somewhere on the Upper right of the screen.  However, if I click the hyperlink buttons the require the page to scroll to the left side of the worksheet it does work.

How can I make it so the target cell is ALWAYS in the upper left of screen after I press the hyperlink button?

Also, how do I know the above code is even running?  The hyperlinks seem to be doing the same thing with or without it.  I just cut and pasted the code into the VBA editor (per google) for thisworkbook.  Is that it or do I need to check something so it will be activated?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do that without using VBA. You can just use a normal hyperlink in the spreadsheet, and link it to "Place in This Document". Make sure you pick the correct Sheet and Type the cell reference that you want to go to (I assume this is A1). This will make sure that whenever you click that particular link, it will always go to that particular spot.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHsWy.png)'s how the edit hyperlink would look in an empty spreadsheet.

Comment: I am currently doing what you have Vf started. However, it does not put the target cell in the upper left corner when the link is pressed. The VBA code is supposed to take care of that. I think the vba code is not executing but I can figure out why. Ideas?

Comment: That's odd, using that method have worked fine for me. Have you run the code on the VBA before? Or did you only just copied it into the worksheet's VBA?

Comment: After more googling it seems if the hyperlink is in a “shape” the VBA code will not run. The hyperlink event is never triggered. I created a normal hyperlink without a shape and the code runs as it should.  Bizarre. No nice buttons :(